# Skype won't launch on Elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki, skype

So i downloaded skype through the official website, then installed gdebi through the terminal, and finally opened the downloaded skype file with gdebi package installer. All went smooth, but skype won't start now. What do i do?

Comment: Are you saying that you've installed it but don't know how to open it? Or that you try to open it and nothing happens?

Comment: @wolf I've installed it, yeah, and when I click the icon, it shows up in Dock, but nothing else happens, it doesn't start.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, just in case something went wrong the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the new [Skype Alpha for Linux](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299). I am using it and it works like a charm.